# Oracle Apex ORDS 17 Standalone Installation

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-ords

How to reconfigure Port for ORDS? If it is set to 8080 SEVERE?

I am getting the following error:

> Could not start Standalone Mode because the listen port: 8080 is
>   already in use by another process. Check if another instance of ords
>   is already running

Answer (score 3):

Goto the config folder. Edit the standalone.properties file.
Change

```
jetty.port=9090
```

Full file will also include docroot , apex image path,and other settings.

```
dhcp-10-10-183-239:ords klrice$ ls
conf        defaults.xml    standalone

dhcp-10-10-183-239:ords klrice$ more standalone/standalone.properties 
#Tue Jul 17 14:52:30 EDT 2018
jetty.port=9090
standalone.access.log=/tmp/ordsLOGS
standalone.context.path=/ords
standalone.doc.root=/Users/klrice/ords/docroot
standalone.scheme.do.not.prompt=true
standalone.static.context.path=/i
standalone.static.path=/Users/klrice/workspace/apex_trunk/images
```